# Win32 GDI and timer issue

Tags: winapi, timer, gdi

I'm trying to achieve blinking text every odd second with the `DrawText` GDI function, but I'm having issues with properly setting up and running timers.

Here is my code:

```
   const int ID_Timer1 = 1;

    SetTimer(hWnd, ID_Timer1, 1000, NULL);

    ...
LRESULT CALLBACK Splash::WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message) {

    case WM_PAINT:
        if((timer%2)==0)
          m_pSplashWnd->OnPaint ( hWnd, true );
        else
          m_pSplashWnd->OnPaint ( hWnd, false);
        break;

    case WM_NCDESTROY:
        delete m_pSplashWnd;
        m_pSplashWnd = NULL;
        break;

    case WM_TIMER:

        switch (wParam)
        {

            case ID_Timer1:
            {
                timer++;

                InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, FALSE);
                UpdateWindow(hWnd);
                break;

            }

        }

    case WM_KEYDOWN:
    case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
    case WM_MBUTTONDOWN:
    case WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN:
    case WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN:
    case WM_NCMBUTTONDOWN:
        m_pSplashWnd->HideSplashScreen();
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I already tried to use dedicated `TimerProc` instead of `WM_TIMER` but the same result...

Comment: I declared of course const int ID_TIMER1 = 1; static long timer = 0L;

Comment: but you not got `WM_PAINT` every second, for got it you need call for example `InvalidateRect` on `WM_TIMER`

Comment: Provide [mcve] please

Comment: here is my wndProc, (RbMm thx for suggestion) I modify but still didn't get to work this is as expected

Comment: oops too long to add as a comment

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `break;` before `case WM_KEYDOWN:`.  On the first `WM_TIMER` received, you fall through and end up hiding the window before it ever gets a chance to repaint.

```
case WM_TIMER:
    switch (wParam)
    {
        case ID_Timer1:
        {
            timer++;
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, FALSE);
            UpdateWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        }
    }
    break; // <-- add this!
```